# ASP.NET MVC RESTFul architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, restful-architecture

Does ASP.NET MVC support RESTful architecture by default?

What I want to know is, if I want to develop a RESTful kind of project, need I to specially work anything on ASP.NET MVC or it will support this feature by default?

Comment: Are you talking about creating RESTful services?

Comment: Yes. I want to create a RESTful service.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Controllers to represent resources and simply implement "actions" that are equal to the HTTP methods, then you can produce a RESTful system very easily with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: can you please elarate more with example in MVC 4 or 5

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC does promote a REST architecture.

See:

- [The REST-Like Aspect Of ASP.NET MVC - Phil Haack, Nov 2007](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/11/09/the-rest-like-aspect-of-asp.net-mvc.aspx)
- [Rest For ASP.NET MVC SDK and Sample - Phil Haack, Aug 2009](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/17/rest-for-mvc.aspx)

Comment: First link returns 404. Should be http://haacked.com/archive/2007/11/09/the-rest-like-aspect-of-asp.net-mvc.aspx/, but too small a change to allow for editing myself.

Comment: How can I applied in MVC application

Comment: @MSTdev i dont understand your question?

Comment: I want to applied RESTful architecture in MVC OR How can I do restful in mvc. Any code ?

Answer (score 2):

MVC has been created with REST in mind. It is **REST-friendly** but not 100% REST compliant, especially when it comes to [content-negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) - although you can implement it yourself **on the top of MVC**.